# How to insert images into QListWidget?

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian

I am new to QT, I am facing some problems in inserting images to list view. This is my current code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QListWidget* list = new QListWidget();
    QListWidgetItem *item1 = new QListWidgetItem(QIcon(":\temp\boat.png"), "BlueHills", list);
    list->insertItem(0, item1);
    QListWidgetItem *item2 = new QListWidgetItem(QIcon("C:\\Documents and Settings\\admin\\Desktop\\icons\\car.png"), "Sunset", list);

    list->show();
}
```

The problem I have is only the text is being displayed.

[How to insert image1](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Getting_image_from_list_in_Qt_for_Symbian)

[how to insert image2](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_use_QListWidget_and_QListWidgetItem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code and pasted it in a brand new QtCreator project and it works. I would suggest you double check your images' paths.

The path for the image of your first item should be ":/temp/boat.png". Make sure that your image is clearly defined in your resource file. I would therefore suggest you to test with an image located in the root of C, for instance `"C://mypic.png"`.

You can add a resource file from within QtCreator using the *New File or Project* dialogue. The *Qt Resource File* is located under *Files and Classes -> Qt*

The resulting file may look something like this:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="images_section">
        <file alias="MyBoatImage">boat.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

If you choose to write it out, you need to add it your .pro file as such:

```
RESOURCES += resource.qrc
```

Whichever way you create the resource file, you can access its resources through something like: `":/images_section/MyBoatImage"`

Comment: Hey.. andy Thanks for the reply dude..
finally it worked..
in order to access the resource we need to give resource prefix, then we need to access the resource.. the example which you have mentioned hepled lot.. Thanks

Comment: Hey... no problem, glad it helped you ! See you!

Comment: How to insert hte image in the place of the text item? I mean, I wish the check box on left and image on right.